# Replacing Vowels with Numbers in a String Using C# or VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to write  an application that accept user input and then replaces the vowels `a e i o u` in the text with `1 2 3 4 5` respectively.
Example:

Inputted Text: *Book*

Output: *B44k*

`oo` replaced  with a number.

Any help???
Preferably: C# or VB.NET

Comment: This is fairly trivial, and I can think of several ways to do it. Have you done any research? tried anything? Show us some code you wrote.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You should research how to replace characters in a string.

Comment: Btw, I edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I can't think of another attempt to explain this to you than to show you the solution:

```
inputString.Replace("a","1").Replace("e","2").Replace("i","3").Replace("o","4").Replace("u","5");
```

You could solve it a little bit more beautiful as well:

```
var vowels = new List<char> {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
string.Join("", inputString.Select(c =>
{
    var i = vowels.IndexOf(c);
    return i == -1 ? c.ToString() : (i + 1).ToString();
}));
```

The first simply replaces each vowel, the second gets the index of the current character in the vowels (it's -1 if it didn't exist in the vowels) and, if it existed it adds 1 to it (I don't know why you didn't start to count with 0) and otherwise takes the normal character.

You can learn more about replace [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

Alternatively you could use a dictionary like that:

```
private static string ReplaceVowels (this string toReplace)
{
    var vowels = new Dictionary<char, char> {{'a', '1'}, {'e', '2'}, {'i', '3'}, {'o', '4'}, {'u', '5'}};
    return string.Join("", toReplace.Select (c => vowels.ContainsKey (c) ? vowels [c] : c));
}
```